# How to get sum of paginated query in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have `User` model and it has `balance` column. I want to paginate User model and get sum of `balance` also.

```
$query = User::where("status", 1)->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work, try it:

```
$query = User::where("status", 1)->query();
$total_balance = $query->sum("balance");
$users = $query->paginate(15);
```